# Mobile menu styling to display the active one

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, menu

So i have a mobile menu, with 4 bobbles in total. 
There is the big bobble which is the active one, and 3 others in a semi circle around it.

I am unable to get two things to work.
with javascript i wanna set the active class for the one clicked so that in turn becomes the big bubble, and the former one goes back in the semi circle. 
That for some reason i am unable to get working.

And with css, the positioning is screwed, if i set the active class on some other. 
I can't get them to work.. 
Hope this makes sense...

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/andrelange91/pen/bGGvjvx

**Html**

```
<nav class="navigation navigation--active">
  <a class="navigation__item navigation__item--inactive">1</a>
  <a class="navigation__item navigation__item--inactive">2</a>
  <a class="navigation__item navigation__item--inactive">3</a>
  <a class="navigation__item navigation__item--active">4</a>
</nav>
```

**Css**

```
.navigation{
  position:fixed;
  right:20px;
  bottom:20px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  .navigation__item{
    padding:10px;
    background-color:green;
    color:white;
    border-radius:50%;
    position:absolute;
    &--active{
      z-index:10;
    }
  }
  &.navigation--active{
      .navigation__item{
        &--inactive{
          &:nth-child(1){
            background-color:purple;
            right: 30px;
            top: 0px;
          }
          &:nth-child(2){
            background-color:blue;
            left:10px;
            top:20px;
          }
          &:nth-child(3){
            background-color:black;
            bottom:0;
            left:10px;
          }
        }
        &--active{
          background-color:red;
          padding:20px;
          right:0;
          bottom:0;
        }

      }
    }
}
```

**And finally my javascript**

```
const elementsArray = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation__item");

for (var i = 0; i < elementsArray.length; i++) {
  elementsArray[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
    console.log(i);
      elementsArray[i].classList.remove("navigation__item--inactive");
      elementsArray[i].classList.add("navigation__item--active");
  });
}
```

I have looked through the documentation for eventlistener, and classlist, but i am unable to get it to work... And with the css, i cannot figure out how to get it to position dynamicly.

Any Help of guidance would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `addEventListener` for each element capture its `click` event and the you can distinguish between the clicked element and the rest of the element using `e.target`
You can use data attributes instead of `nth-child` this way you can reorder the numbers

```js
const elementsArray = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation__item");
const inactiveElementsArray = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation__item--inactive");
for (var i = 0; i < elementsArray.length; i++) {
    elementsArray[i].addEventListener('click', changeSize, false);
  
}
function changeSize(e){
  for (var i = 0; i < elementsArray.length; i++) {
    elementsArray[i].classList.remove("navigation__item--active");
    elementsArray[i].classList.add("navigation__item--inactive");
  }
  e.target.classList.remove("navigation__item--inactive");
  e.target.classList.add("navigation__item--active");
  e.target.setAttribute('data-position', "main");
  elementsOrder();
}
function elementsOrder(){
  for (var i = 0; i < inactiveElementsArray.length; i++) {
    inactiveElementsArray[i].setAttribute('data-position', i);
  }

}
```

```css
.navigation {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.navigation .navigation__item {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
.navigation .navigation__item--active {
  z-index: 10;
}
.navigation__item--inactive[data-position="0"] {
  background-color: purple;
  right: 30px;
  top: 0px;
}
.navigation__item--inactive[data-position="1"] {
  background-color: blue;
  left: 10px;
  top: 20px;
}
.navigation__item--inactive[data-position="2"] {
  background-color: black;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10px;
}
.navigation.navigation--active .navigation__item--active {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation navigation--active">
  <a class="navigation__item navigation__item--inactive" data-position="0">1</a>
  <a class="navigation__item navigation__item--inactive" data-position="1">2</a>
  <a class="navigation__item navigation__item--inactive" data-position="2">3</a>
  <a class="navigation__item navigation__item--active" data-position="main">4</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: I thought that was what i was doing.. Any ideas about the styling ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about styling, but you can open a new question describing what you want to get and what you tried already.

Comment: it was part of the original question, about the screwed positioning, once the active class changes to another bobble

Comment: @andrelange91 I've added the styling fix as well

Comment: Thx, did not think of adding a position.